# Error on Member Dashboard after upgrading to PHP 7.0

Tags: dashboard, user-dashboard

After Upgrading to PHP 7.0 - I keep getting the following error on the Member Dashboard.  Do you know what causes this? This happened to be before - I changed the resource URLs to Absolute and that fixed it - now this error is back.

`Warning: get_headers(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php on line 903

Warning: get_headers(): This function may only be used against URLs in /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php on line 903`

I should also note that the System Status Page mentions that the "The Resource URL is not set correctly."  even though it is.

**Update:** Thanks to Yurg's answer below - I contacted the webhost - they store PHP options elsewhere - I was able to change settings to allow_url_fopen=1 and that fixed everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `allow_url_fopen=1` should be set in PHP.ini file on your web host.

Comment: Its enabled by default on the server - but I added to PHP,ini anyways. Issue still persists. Luckily error only shows up as Admin.

Comment: Actually - my host stored the settings elsewhere - I was able to change the settings to allow_url_fopen=1 - Thank you!